# Компиляция аллокатора

Tags: c, malloc

Решил добавить себе этот [git](https://github.com/vhotspur/buddy-memory-allocator) аллокатор, но для начала хотел протестировать его работу. Скачал все файлы, зашел в папку, написал команду make и увидел

```
buddy.c:214:2: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat=]
  TRACE_FLOW("(%lu)", sizesCount);
  ^
buddy.c:227:2: warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
  MARK_BLOCK_FREE(sizeof(Address) * 2);
  ^
```

И еще много таких же warning для других функций. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а когда подключаю .c к своему файлу, вылезает еще и куча  подобных                   buddy.c:178: multiple definition of `buddyInit' и

Comment: Какая версия компилятора/make? У меня gcc 5.4.0, GNU Make 4.1, ни одного предупреждения или ошибки. `когда подключаю .c к своему файлу` -- как именно, что значит "подключаю"?

Comment: @PinkTux 4.8.4; Под подключаю я имелл ввиду: добавил #include "buddy.h" в основное тело программы и компилировал так gcc  buddy.c main.c

Comment: у меня есть предположение, что у @Horambe 32битный компилятор.

Comment: Да. i386, значит 32 битная. Что тогда делать?

Comment: просто для 32битной системы либо игнорировать эти ворнинги, либо просто поправить.